# How to apply custom cascading security on Entity Framework ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

**Setting the scene**

We have an ASP .NET Core application using Entity Framework code-first.

In our application, we have a number of different relational objects with user customisable data access permissions. These permissions consist of user allow/deny rules and group allow/deny rules (groups being a collection of users).

We also have a number of inheritance lines occurring. As an example, there may be a `Town` object, a `Street` object, a `House` object and a `Room` object. Permissions (user/group allow/deny) can be set against each of these objects.

- `Town` has `Streets` as a navigation property
- `Street` has `Houses` as a navigation property
- `House` has `Rooms` as a navigation property

You cannot access a `Room` unless you satisfy the allow/deny rules set on the `Room` itself, the parent `House`, the parent `Street` and the parent `Town`.

What is the best way to configure this in Entity Framework keeping in mind performance issues?

**Current Configuration**

We currently have a custom filter expression in our `DbContext` which checks whatever object is being accessed:

```
// Allow access if user on user or group allow list and not a denied user or group
entityExpression = t =>
            ((((IFullAuditedEntityWithSecurity)t).Permissions.Any(security => security.UserId == AbpSession.UserId && security.PermissionState == PermissionState.Allow) ||
            ((IFullAuditedEntityWithSecurity)t).Permissions.Any(security => security.Group.Members.Any(p => p.UserId == AbpSession.UserId) && security.PermissionState == PermissionState.Allow)) &&
            !((IFullAuditedEntityWithSecurity)t).Permissions.Any(security => security.UserId == AbpSession.UserId && security.PermissionState == PermissionState.Deny) &&
            !((IFullAuditedEntityWithSecurity)t).Permissions.Any(security => security.Group.Members.Any(p => p.UserId == AbpSession.UserId) && security.PermissionState == PermissionState.Deny)) ||
            ((IFullAuditedEntityWithSecurity)t).AllowPublicAccess;
```

Problems with security start to occur when checking the inheritance line, for example:

```
// If street, check parent town security
if (typeof(IStreet).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> parentSecurity = t => ((IStreet)t).Town != null;
    parentSecurity = isBeingAdded != null ? parentSecurity.Or(isBeingAdded) : parentSecurity;
    expression = expression == null ? parentSecurity : CombineExpressions(expression, parentSecurity);
}

// If house, check parent street security
if (typeof(IHouse).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> parentSecurity = t => ((IHouse)t).Street != null;
    parentSecurity = isBeingAdded != null ? parentSecurity.Or(isBeingAdded) : parentSecurity;
    expression = expression == null ? parentSecurity : CombineExpressions(expression, parentSecurity);
}

// If room item, check parent house security
if (typeof(IRoom).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> parentSecurity = t => ((IRoom)t).House != null;
    parentSecurity = isBeingAdded != null ? parentSecurity.Or(isBeingAdded) : parentSecurity;
    expression = expression == null ? parentSecurity : CombineExpressions(expression, parentSecurity);
}
```

We also have some additional filters so that users can get auto access to child elements if they already have access to parent objects. For example, if a user is a town member they get auto access to any child streets:

```
if (typeof(IStreet).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> allowTownMembersExpression = t =>
                ((IStreet)t).Town.Members.Any(townMember => townMember.UserId == AbpSession.UserId && townMember.StartDate <= DateTime.Now && (townMember.EndDate >= DateTime.Now || townMember.EndDate == null)) &&
                !((IFullAuditedEntityWithSecurity)t).Permissions.Any(security => security.Group.Members.Any(p => p.UserId == AbpSession.UserId) && security.PermissionState == PermissionState.Deny) &&
                !((IFullAuditedEntityWithSecurity)t).Permissions.Any(security => security.UserId == AbpSession.UserId && security.PermissionState == PermissionState.Deny);

    entityExpression = entityExpression == null ? allowTeamMembersExpression : entityExpression.Or(allowTeamMembersExpression);
}
```

This is all working nicely, except for the fact the performance is not the greatest. Using profiler we can see that the scripts generated any time we try to access any object are huge to say the least. The security checks on all the parent objects and the subsequent get of users, groups, group members foreach one of those parent objects in resulting in scripts that are way too slow and way too big.

Considering that this is our business case and we need to enforce this inheritance security system, is there any other way of going around it that would still satisfy the business logic but be less of a load on the database every time we access any object?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Note: The problem with relational database is the depth of relations. We get the best where we reduce these relations.

I have a world of objects and each object has a set of permissions and through this permissions actors of our world are able to access to specific object.

In my point of view I break it to two phase validation on Permissions: **1.Submission** and **2.Evaluation**

**1.Submission Phase:**
In this phase a I'm about to edit these permissions (I assumed that permission editing is a low repetition task **vs** reading permissions, **That's a key point**). In this phase I will apply the most overheads possible. I will check permission inheritances, cascading permission evaluating, conditional permission checking and the all other situations that are imposed by my application requirements.
At the end of the story I just store something like this `Alice has permission x on Object y`, maybe something like this:

```
 ObjectY.PermissionSet.Add(new PermissionGrant() 
 { 
     Type = "Walking", 
     Actor = "Alice", 
     Access = "Granted" 
 });
```

I have only 1 relation in this implementation. `MyWorldObject` to `PermissionSet`. Thats a lots of performance enhancement.

**2.Evaluation Phase:**
In this phase I just want to check whether `Alice` has permission `X` on  street `Y` or not. Thats a simple task, low overhead. I just fetch the street object and I will looking for `Alice` there.

I'm not satisfied with this implementation still, because I have a growing number of `Actors` and I have to store a lots of records on `PermissionGrant` table (in my example). I will go through using `indexes` on this table. maybe composite indexes. ([Read more on indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver16).)

If you are still not satisfied with this implementation you should go for caching scenarios.

Main issue with this implementation is updating permissions and lake of permission inferences.

- You can lower updating cost based on the occurrence of `Acccess` and `Update` operations. to lower this cost you should balance these checkings between `Submission` and `Evaluation` phase.
- About permission inference, someone might say **What happens when I update the database manually?** whole application crashes. That may happens we are not responsible for illegal access to database. There might be a tons application crash caused by illegal access to our database.

Comment: Thank you @RezaNoei this was really helpful for us